# Getting strange characters from single item of a ListView

Tags: java, android

I'm trying getting the data from a ListAdapter but I'm getting stranges values. And I cannot re-use this values in another method.

```
    private void updateList() {

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mCommentList,
            R.layout.single_post, new String[] { title, message,
                    username }, new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.message,
                    R.id.username });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            String aux = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


            //To display "You Clicked at {message=hello, username=myself, title=hello }"
             Toast.makeText(ReadComments.this, "You Clicked at " + aux, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //I want only display "myself" (the content of username), but I get strange values like a lot of numbers.
            //"You Clicked at android.widget.TextView{b40a1c10 V.ED ..........5,35-45,56#7f060002 app:id/message}
             Toast.makeText(ReadComments.this, "You Clicked at " + view.findViewById(R.id.message).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

How can I use the "myself" item in another method and performance a toast message?
Any ideas?

Comment: You'll have to cast your TextView, with:(TextView)view.findViewById(Resource);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lv.getItemAtPosition(position) returns a Map object that was put in the list. 
The below code is I believe should work;

```
Map map = (Map) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);

String title = map.get("title");
String message = map.get("message");
String username= map.get("username");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call to *lv.getItemAtPosition(position)* is returning a regular java Object and you are calling the *toString()* method for that general java Object. This gives you a string containing  the class name, the HexString version of the object's hashCode. This string seems not to be what you want. So, casting to String on that default string is not helping you.

Instead, get the object by calling getItemAtPosition() (as your listAdapter seems to be populated with String values). As I explained already, you don't need to call toString() at that point.

So, your revised code should look like this:

```
private void updateList() {

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mCommentList,
        R.layout.single_post, new String[] { title, message,
                username }, new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.message,
                R.id.username });

setListAdapter(adapter);

final ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        String aux = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(ReadComments.this, "You Clicked at " + aux, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(ReadComments.this, "You Clicked at " + view.findViewById(R.id.message).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you used the TextView in R.id.message, so you are accessing the object hash table id (by calling toString),

**Solution**

Replace this line

((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.message)).getText().toString();

Instead of

view.findViewById(R.id.message).toString()